# Running Script Module on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

currently I need to import .CSV file into my application.

I found that this code (that made by previous developer) will be use as importer. But I am not sure how to run this script. Is it different with /tasks ? Since when I run `rake -T` it doesn't showing.

```
require 'csv'

module Migrators
  module Groups
    class << self

      def import!
        Post.skip_callback :create, :before, :set_last_action_at
        Post.skip_callback :create, :after, :create_memberhip_of_owner

        CSV.foreach(Rails.root.to_s + '/db/lagacy/groups.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
          group = Group.new(row.to_hash)
          group.save(:validate => false)
        end
        # Update last_action_at to created_at
        Group.where('last_action_at IS NULL').update_all('last_action_at = created_at')
        Group.find_by_sql("SELECT setval('groups_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM groups))")

        Post.set_callback :create, :before, :set_last_action_at
        Post.set_callback :create, :after, :create_memberhip_of_owner
      end

    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rake task for that.

Create a rake file .rake in lib/tasks/ with the following syntax:

```
namespace :yourtask_namespace do
  desc "task description" (it is optional but recommended, this way if you do "rake -T yourtask" it will show your task)
  task :yourtask_name => :environment do
    Migrators::Groups.import!
  end
end
```

Then you can call it with "rake your_task_namespace:your_task_name" with optional RAILS_ENV= if it isn't dev.

I'm at work and can't specify more the sample.

Hope it helps.

Here is an example of rake task: [rake task](http://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/)

EDIT:

If you can't create rake tasks, you can create an script file this way:

add to the first line of the file `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

In the last line of your file.. call the method you want to execute and just run the script.

Comment: Hello Juan, thank you for your answer. I understand that rake tasks will be easier, but since this is old code by the previous developer, I can't change or add any codes into the application. I need to use that old code.

Comment: ok, so add this to the first line of the file: #!/usr/bin/env ruby and give execution permissions and run it as an script

Comment: Hello Juan, thank you again for your reply. So these lines will be put on which file?

Comment: Add it to the file where the code you posted is, or copy+paste to a new file. and remember to call chmod 777 <file.rb>